# ScrollView steals focus when scrolling

Tags: android, view, focus

I am trying to make a chatting window.
There's a TextView wrapped in a ScrollView in the upper side of the screen; and a EditText in the bottom of the screen.
I use following code to make the ScrollView scroll automatically when the new message is out of view.

```
scroll.post(new Runnable(){
@Override
public void run() {
       scroll.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
}
});
```

Something annoying is when the ScrollView scrolls, it steals my focus from the EditText.
I can't input my message when the ScrollView is scrolling.
Can anybody give me some light? Thanks a lot : )

Answer (score 1):

I know a workaround. Call requestFocus on the view that should keep the focus.

It would be nice to know if you solved it in a better way.